# 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Web.Extensions.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo una aplicación que devuelve una lista de datos, `List <t>` a través de un método web que desde el principio funcionó bien , hasta que la cantidad de registros devueltos pasó de 300, intente usar try catch para ver en qué parte del código se genera el error y solo cuando el método termina de ejecutarse genera la siguiente excepción.

> 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Web.Extensions.dll

Este es el Código:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string cargarRegNacViv(string dato, string opc, string fechaMin, string fechaMax)
{
    List<CRRegNacViv> RegNacVivs = new List<CRRegNacViv>();
    if (opc == "Código RUAF")
    {
        CRCodRuaf CodRuaf = DAOCRCodRuaf.getCodRuaf(dato);
        RegNacVivs = DAOCRRegNacViv.getRegNacViv(Convert.ToString(CodRuaf.IntOIdCRCodRuaf), opc);
    }
    else
        RegNacVivs = DAOCRRegNacViv.getRegNacVivs(dato, opc);

    List<double> codRuaf = new List<double>();
    foreach (CRRegNacViv NacViv in RegNacVivs)
    {
        codRuaf.Add(DAOCRCodRuaf.getCodRuafId(Convert.ToString(NacViv.IntCRCodRuaf)).DoubleCRcodRuaf);
    }

    Object[] datos = { RegNacVivs, codRuaf };
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(datos);
}
```

Comment: Has comprobado si alguno de esos registros es nulo?

Comment: SI amigo, de echo la aplicación  no me nuestra ningún error  hasta que el método se ha ejecutado completamente